# How can I tell what my parameter values are?

Tags: c#, code-behind

Here's a snippet of my code-behind:

```
SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(str2);
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd2.CommandText = "" + MyRptSproc + "";
cmd2.Connection = connection2;


//Set up the parameters, if they exist
if (MyUseDates != "N")
{
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@StDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtStDate.Value);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EnDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtEnDate.Value);
}

if (MyPlatform != "N")
{
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyPlatform", cboPlatform.SelectedValue));
}

if (MyManager != "N")
{
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyManager", cboManager.SelectedValue));
}

if (MyAuditManager != "N")
{
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyAuditManager", cboAuditorManager.SelectedValue));
}

if (MySampleTitle != "N")
{
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MySampleTitle", cboSampleTitle.SelectedValue));
}

if (MyAuditType != "N")
{
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyAuditType", cboAuditType.SelectedValue));
}

if (MyLocation != "N")
{
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyLocation", cboLocation.SelectedValue));
}


try
{
connection2.Open();
GridView_Reports.EmptyDataText = "No Records Found";
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
var ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "MyTableName");

// Add this to a session variable so the datagrid won't get NULLed out on repost
Session["SSRptMenu"] = ds;

GridView_Reports.DataSource = ds;
GridView_Reports.DataBind();
```

So I'm stepping through this code and I get to

```
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
```

I highlight "cmd2" and it tells me what server it's looking at, what the command text is, etc...  It also tells me that there are 5 parameters selected for this particular case.

My question is; how can I tell which parameters are selected, and what their values are?  I've drilled down through just about every menu item and can't seem to find it.

[image]

Comment: you've added them to `Parameters`. What do you see when you look there?

Comment: Well, how about a defining `SqlParameterCollection` at the top of your code and add them if your conditions are `true` then check your collection at the end?

Comment: It says there are 5, but I can't find any menu item under it that says what those 5 are.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: I would expect that to be of type `SqlParameterCollection` which is expandable to show the items in the collection. Perhaps you could put a screenshot of what you are seeing there instead of the connection object (or as well as if you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else needs this info, I found it under:

```
cmd2 -->   
  Parameters -->
    base -->
      base -->
        Non-Public members -->
          [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection] -->
             _items -->
```

That's where you can find the list of parameters, then under each parameter you can find its value.